# Is there a portable OpenGL UI Library (Buttons, Lists, Windows, Dropdown etc)?

Tags: c++, iphone, user-interface, opengl-es

I'm searching for a OpenGL User Interface Library like WxWidgets but not OS dependent.

It would have to provide callbacks for user input since this is OS dependent.

If something like this doesn't yet exist (which I doubt because most games have most of the Basic UI Elements) is there a OpenGL HTML/CSS renderer?

Answer (score 3):

FLTK, GTK+, and QT support OpenGL widgets in a portable way. QT in particular can [render all of its widgets in an OpenGL viewport](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/06/27/accelerate-your-widgets-with-opengl/). I know there's been some work on getting GTK to do the same thing, but I haven't heard on the progress of it.

[OTK](http://otk.sourceforge.net/) comes up on a quick Google search as an OpenGL-backed widget library.

It's also worth pointing out that [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) has an OpenGL backend, and there are a number of toolkits that depend on it, including GTK+.